# .png application icon in KDE4?

Tags: icons, kde

Possibly stupid question, but:

I'm creating links to some applicatons on my KDE4 desktop. If I change the icon to a built-in system icon, it displays correctly. If I try to change it to an custom icon, the icon stays as the default question-mark.

When I navigate to Desktop in a file browser, the thumbnail for the .desktop file is correct, and when I open the file, the `icon` property is set correctly, i.e:

`Icon=/home/$USER/$APPNAME/$APPNAME.png`

But it doesn't show up that way on the desktop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow-up for anyone else, I ended up having to convert the icon from png to xpm. You definitely used to be able to use png files directly in KDE3, but I guess this must have changed.